# Java Calendar/SimpleDateFormat giving invalid date

Tags: java, android, calendar, simpledateformat

I am fairly new to java and I am creating a fitness application.

Context: Database should add a new date entry every day the app is opened

Problem: Opened the app yesterday and it successfully added the date: 31.1.21. However opened it today and database has added 32.2.21 when it should be 1.2.21. Logs indicate that it must be an error with the code...

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    timeStamp = timeStamp + " 00:00:00.000";
    android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Date/Time: " + timeStamp);
```

The code above is what is causing this issue, I am not familiar with Calendar and kindly ask if anyone knows what the issue could be. Many thanks.

Comment: Why you are adding this: ` " 00:00:00.000"`
`String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());`

This line is enough

Comment: Hi Soumik, I have added  " 00:00:00.000" to the current date because I want the database to acknowledge a new entry to be added at the start of each day. This is simply hard coded. Since it is a string concatenated to the end of the date it should not have any effect on the outcome?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't affect, but as your code seems perfect to me, I was concerned about that line. Can you please log this line: `new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());` and see if it works or not.

Comment: Just logged without the added string: D/StepCounter: Date/Time: 2021-02-32

Comment: Found solution:

"YYYY-MM-DD" should be "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: Yeah, I just saw.. Learned something new.. I had no idea about the difference between dd & DD..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

"YYYY-MM-DD" should be "yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got what went wrong there:

In DateFormat **DD** means Days in the year.. Whereas **dd** means Days in a month

So, the format should be this: **"yyyy-MM-dd"** instead of **"YYYY-MM-DD"**

Comment: Hi thank you I have found the answer already. Thanks for your time and contribution though :)